# Upload File in chunks to URL Endpoint using Guzzle PHP

Tags: php, stream, guzzle6, guzzle

I want to upload files in chunks to a URL endpoint using guzzle.

I should be able to provide the Content-Range and Content-Length headers.

Using php I know I can split using

```
define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*1024); // Size (in bytes) of chunk

function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) {
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt    = 0;
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');

    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();

        if ($retbytes) {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }
    }

    $status = fclose($handle);

    if ($retbytes && $status) {
        return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
    }

    return $status;
}
```

How Do I achieve sending the files in chunk using guzzle, if possible using guzzle streams?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guzzle 6 Large file uploads / Chunking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641050/guzzle-6-large-file-uploads-chunking)

Answer (score 3):

This method allows you to transfer large files using guzzle streams:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$resource = fopen($pathname, 'r');
$stream = Psr7\stream_for($resource);

$client = new Client();
$request = new Request(
        'POST',
        $api,
        [],
        new Psr7\MultipartStream(
            [
                [
                    'name' => 'bigfile',
                    'contents' => $stream,
                ],
            ]
        )
);
$response = $client->send($request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `multipart` body type as it's [described in the documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart). cURL then handles the file reading internally, you don't need to so implement chunked read by yourself. Also all required headers will be configured by Guzzle.